# Linear regression over several data sheets and different time frames

Tags: r, automation, linear-regression, estimation

I have a more complex problem in R and hope you can help me. I am trying to create linear regressions over two data sheets and many different time frames.

To explain my problem more precisely, I will include the two datasets I have a the moment

Dataset "Deals" including one M&A Deals and several characteristics per row

| Deal Number | Announcement Date | ... | ... | ... | CUSIP (ID) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2157920020 | 2010-02-21 | ... | ... | ... | ***589499102*** (=CUSIP ID 3) | ... |
| 2164370020 | 2010-03-14 | ... | ... | ... | 705573103 | ... |
| 2166589020 | 2010-03-21 | ... | ... | ... | 46069S109 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Dataset "daily_return" include the daily returns derived from the stock price of the acquirer of the M&A Deal (In one column are the returns for one stock for the time period 2009-01-05 - 2020-12-31):

| Date | CUSIP (ID) 1 (002824100) | CUSIP (ID) 2 (00430U103) | CUSIP (ID) 3 (***589499102***) | ... | ... | Benchmark Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2009-01-05 | -0.01717700 | 0.0022422 | -0.038760 | ... | ... | 0.016764 |
| 2009-01-06 | -0.03267477 | -0.0044743 | 0.016129 | ... | ... | 0.033647 |
| 2009-01-07 | -0.00549882 | -0.1146067 | 0.031746 | ... | ... | -0.022271 |
| 2009-01-08 | 0.01105845 | 0.0329949 | 0.0076923 | ... | ... | 0.011896 |
| 2009-01-09 | -0.00058594 | -0.0491400 | 0.046512 | ... | ... | -0.018748 |
| 2009-01-12 | -0.02169240 | -0.0051680 | -0.022222 | ... | ... | -0.026589 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-12-31 | 0.03292349 | -0.0031726 | -0.1029381 | ... | ... | 0.0213947 |

I would like to create linear regressions of the different securities on the benchmark. However, the estimation window used in the regression should always have the same length of 253 days and should start 283 days before the individual Announcement date. I made an example for CUSIP ID 3. The Regression is from row [3:255] as row 3 is 283 days before the announcement and row 255 is 31 days before the announcement.

`` linear_model <- lm(daily_return$`589499102`[3:255] ~ daily_return$`Benchmark Index`[3:255]) ``

I was able to "automate" the row numbers by the which-function, so I get the row numbers automatically:
`which(strategic_return$Date == "2010-02-22")-283` --> returns row 3

`which(strategic_return$Date == "2010-02-22")-31` --> returns row 255

My problem now is in combing and automating the mentioned steps:

1. The code should start at the top of "Deals" data set and identify the announcement date of the first deal on the sheet. E.g. Recognize that for the CUSIP 589499102 in the first row that the announcement date is 2010-02-21.
2. Next it should identify the correct column on the "daily_return" sheet as they don't have the same order and some acquirers have more than one deal within the last 11 years (e.g. that would be column 4). The Column CUSIP (ID) from the "Deals" data set contains the exact same contents as the headers of the "daily_return" data set.
3. As the date already is identified (step 1) it should now be able to find out the time frame for the regression which is [announcement day -283 : announcement day -31 ]
4. With this information the regression should be able to be conducted for the individual stock and the outcomes should be stored
5. Repeat these steps for all rows in "Deals"

There is one more obstacle to tackle as the announcement date in the deals data frame can be on a weekend e.g. 2010-02-21 while this date is not on the daily_returns data frame (as it is a weekend). In that case, it should just calculate with the next available date e.g. 2010-02-22.

I know it is a lot and I am not sure if it is feasible at all. But maybe someone has an idea how to proceed.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The name of the data frame should NOT be in the formula. It should be given as the data= argument of lm. If you want to subset the rows then use the subset= argument of lm.

Comment: Okay thank you - I managed to change that to linear_model <- lm(`589499102`[3:255] ~ `Benchmark Index`[3:255], data = daily_return)

Comment: Try lm(\`589499102\` ~ \`Benchmark Index\`, data = daily_return, subset = 3:255)

Comment: Nice - this works perfectly es well. Now, I managed to create a dataset where all the starting and ending rows are defined for the individual securities. 

How can I link this table with the return table above to automate the regressions? Do you have an idea?